# dialog window in iOS does not show when called from another class after application has been loaded

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created a function in Class A that creates a dialog window that should appear whenever my application has been loaded. So in my AppDelegate.swift file I would call instance of Class A. This instance calls the function that should show dialog window. The problem is that when my application loads and even when my application finishes loading I am not seeing my dialog window. I believe that the problem is that whenever I call in my funcion:

```
present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

that at that point my view controller is still visible. I think that I need to figure out that the refreshAlert is presented on the top of window hierarchy. Can anybody help me to figure out this issue.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case you want to present the controller from App Delegate try this:**

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are not sure why the alert is not displayed in your class that is loaded from App Delegate, try to put a debugger there on the alert and see if the control passes to the alert at the same time as the class loads.
If that's the case, then you should try to put a delay and then present the alert something like:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.5, execute: {
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

or maybe try to put the alert in the `func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` or trigger it after the control reaches `viewDidAppear` .

Comment: let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks Umar, using DispatchQueue.main.async with the delay did the job.

Comment: @Juventus I'm glad it worked for you ! You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not calling it from the main thread.

Use DispatchQueue.main.async to send it to the main thread